# Can two Lists be joined if types are different like List<T> and List<G>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, lambda

I have two different classes like below:

```
public class ProductDto : IDto
    {
        public int Parentproductid { get; set; }
        public string Parentproductnumber { get; set; }
        public int Supplierid { get; set; }
        //More properties
    }

    public class OrderItemsDto : IDto
    {
        public int Poid { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Createddate { get; set; }
        public int Parentproductid { get; set; }
        public int Variationid { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Deliverydate { get; set; }
        //More properties
    }
```

What I need to do is basically to join `List<OrderItemsDto>` and `List<ProductDto>` on parentproductid (like if they were database tables) and produce another list.

I have tried using `Union` like below:

```
List<ProductDto> productParents = productManager.getList();
List<OrderItemsDto> orderItemsList = ordermanager.getList();
gvPurchaseOrderItems.DataSource =  orderItemsList.Select(o => o.Parentproductid).Union(productParents.Select(pp => pp.parentproductid));
```

But this only gives me a result of the `List<int>` parentproductids found in both of the lists where I need something that has properties ( columns in above case ) from both classes. And I couldn't find how to select multiple properties with the Select extension method ( I am kind of a beginner )

I know I can create a new class and map the properties manually, but I really am curious about how to do this with lambda expressions or linq. Is this possible, I would really appreciate if you could point me a direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Select` to create an anonymous type for your query:

```
orderItemsList.Select(o => new { o.Parentproductid, o.Variationid, /* etc */ })
```

So, in your case:

```
gvPurchaseOrderItems.DataSource =  orderItemsList
    .Select(o => new { o.Parentproductid, o.Variationid, /* etc */ })
    .Union(productParents
        .Select(pp => new { pp.Parentproductid, pp.Variationid, /* etc */ }));
```

Comment: Thank you, I had something like this in mind but I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

As both `ProductDto` and `OrderItemsDto` implements `IDto` interface, no need for anonymous types as you tried, this should work:

```
gvPurchaseOrderItems.DataSource =  orderItemsList.Cast<IDto>().Union(productParents);
```

All the common properties (i.e. defined in the interface I assume) will be there, along with the type-specific ones using another casting.

According to your comment (and the fact that it's DTOs, silly me), you should definitely go for Dave Bish's answer.

Comment: No common properties, the Interface is mostly there because there is a generic repository behind. Additionally, I need to somehow specify the properties that will show on the gridView. I don't want to use [Browsable(false)] because I may need to display them on some other page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join two lists on `Parentproductid` into one list, try:

```
var result = from pm in productManager
             join om in ordermanager on pm.Parentproductid equals om.Parentproductid
             select new { pm.Parentproductid, pm.Parentproductnumber,
                          pm.Supplierid, om.Poid /* more properties */ };
```